# How to inject app.context into Loopback 4 controller

Tags: loopbackjs

I cannot find any suitable example on how to inject an app.context object into a Loopback 4 controller being in a separate file

This inline example from the documentation works fine

```
import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
import {Application} from '@loopback/core';

const app = new Application();
app.bind('defaultName').to('John');

export class HelloController {
  constructor(@inject('defaultName') private name: string) {}

  greet(name?: string) {
    return `Hello ${name || this.name}`;
  }
}
```

but I cannot find a way to obtain the same having my controller in a separate file.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
export class PingController {
  constructor(@inject(app.name) private name: string)
```

app.name being a simple binding in my app-context.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was quite simple.

Since all context values on app level is available throughout the application, no reference to app is required.

I just needed to replace (app.name) with ('name') in the constructor injection.

Comment: how do you get the app on a controller class.